# jquery mobile pagination of one horizontal scrolling DIV

Tags: jquery, mobile, pagination, swipe

I'd like to create an article and break it up into pages with columns - 2 in vertical mode or 3 in horizontal mode. The users should be able to move from one page to another (like many magazine-like apps on iOS). The jquery mobile plugin "pagination" does exactly what I'm looking for, but for separate pages: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_mobile_pagination_plugin/. To create a column layout that re-flows depending on screen size and orientation I need to create one long horizontal `DIV` that scrolls to the right (and then back to the left).How do I achieve this swipe gesture ?